# Access a Hashmap within a Hashmap, and print it out in a format

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

```
    static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<Integer>>> BIGMAP= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<Integer>>>();
```

This is a Hashmap if i were to print it out this is what i get:

```
SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(BIGMAP.keySet());
     for (String key : keys) {
     HashMap<String, List<Integer>> value = kmap.get(key);
     System.out.println(key + " : " + value);

     }

a.txt : {a=[20], to=[10]}
b.txt : {a=[4, 20], by=[16], is=[2], to=[13, 22]}
c.txt : {a=[15], as=[16, 17], in=[34], do=[9], to=[14]}
```

So i am trying to iterate through this "BIGMAP" the above for each key a.txt(String) there is a Value which is another map the structure of `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>`

...

OUTPUT:

```
a [15],[20],[4, 20],
as [16, 17],, ,, ,
by , ,, ,[16],
...so on...
...so on...
...so on...
```

EXPECTED/WANTED OUTPUT

```
a  20, 4:20 ,15
as   ,  , 16:17
by   , 16 ,
```

the printing format should be like above but obviously it should print in order from each textfile(string) which is a key in the outer hashmap

for example `a  20, 4:20 ,15`
"a" is word FOR That word , `20` is from the value where key is`a.txt` and `4:20` is from `b.txt` and `15` is from `c.txt`

As you can see i have something up there but its not doing exactly what i need. The colons are necessary to where there multiple numbers. it can ever sometimes be `4:20:50:92`

Comment: Why did you delete your old question and repost it?

Comment: @cricket_007just edited it to make more sense and see if anyone would look at it

Comment: If you edit a post, it gets bumped to the front page again (which is how I saw it). There is no need to delete. And did my LinkedHashMap suggestion change anything? Sorry I can't answer more than that without seeing how data is entered into `BIGMAP`

Comment: Is the key sort alphabetical or by insertion order?

Comment: Do the output keys need to be sorted?

Comment: @shmosel yes they need to be alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job in Java 8. Not my best work, but tested successfully with your sample values.

```
BIGMAP.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream())
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .map(k -> k
                + " "
                + BIGMAP.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted(comparing(Entry::getKey))
                        .map(e -> e.getValue()
                                   .getOrDefault(k, Collections.emptyList())
                                   .stream()
                                   .map(String::valueOf)
                                   .collect(joining(":")))
                        .collect(joining(", ")))
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Produces the following output:

```
a 20, 4:20, 15
as , , 16:17
by , 16, 
do , , 9
in , , 34
is , 2, 
to 10, 13:22, 14
```